# Issue with redirecting to a URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

I have a website were i show some result from different providers combined.And on selection i take them to the original sites booking page.

The issue i am facing is there is a Url : `http://www.abc.xx/booking.aspx?someparameters`

If i do this from my page to open this booking page:

```
window.open(result, "_blank");
```

The Url opens in a new tab but gives some error, but if i copy paste the same Url in the same browser next to the failed tab and hit Go , it works perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: "gives some error" What's the error.

Comment: No error , moves to the link but the link shows error like not recognized etc...

Comment: Have you tried using 'ResolveUrl'? I've had to use this in some circumstances: http://forums.asp.net/t/1488825.aspx?what+is+Page+ResolveUrl

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot open your url in new tab** rather you can give a try with popup window.

**For popup window**

The issue is with may be of "" (double quotes),

Try by using the line below,

```
var red = window.open(result, '_blank');
red.Focus();
```

It will fail when your popup has blocked in your browser. Try by allowing popup in your browser.

Comment: It is an external site url.

Answer (score 0):

suppose bookedStatus is your parameter

```
var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/booking.aspx?bookedStatus="+bStatus;
    window.parent.open(url, "_blank");
```

window.location.host: This enables you to get the domain name or IP address of the current URL
window.parent.open : this allows you to open the window in new tab

Comment: I do not want to open the URL for current domain, i have an external Url that i want to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `http://` before its url for external site url.
e.g.

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
```

Hope this will help you.